# How to set and pass a session variable from a twig template to a controller in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, session, twig

I have a confirmation message in my Twig template that takes "Yes" or "No" as an answer (Buttons). How can I set a string variable that can take "Yes" or "No" as values, and pass it to my controller as a session object?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: You can set it at Javascript level and pass those vars to your function in a AJAX call for example, is that right for you?

Comment: This 'confirmation' message is just a form? Treat it as any other form with inputs and actions - including the action it executes. It sounds as though you have a 'dialog' that has more than one state. How you want the controller to action it is up to you. Different actions on the controller or different parameters to the same controller action.